# How can I fix npx create-react-app error?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm having trouble making a react project for the first time and I'm basically doing `npx create-react-app portfolio` and this is the log in the terminal

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...w2l6C\nBZrjaE2TabX86o'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ITland\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-13T14_28_52_450Z-debug.log
Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts
cra-template has failed.
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting portfolio/ from C:\Users\ITland\Desktop\New folder (2)
```

Has anyone any idea what's causing this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Log message shown above indicates that the npx command was run inside the folder -

**C:\Users\ITland\Desktop\New folder (2)**

The npm command can sometimes fail on Windows due to blank spaces or special chars in the folder names.

It is always recommended to avoid spaces and special characters in the folder names where npm is run.

The above problem may be resolved by running the npm / npx command inside

**C:\Users\ITland\Desktop\New_folder_2**

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below command

```js
npm cache clean --force
```

Once this is successful, try doing what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following way:

> `npm cache clean --force`

If you are a `windows` user, try deleting all files in this folder:

> C:\Users{{your-username}}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

Then...

> `npm cache verify`

If that doesn't work, try updating to the lastest

> `npm i npm@latest -g`